# What is the latest MSVC that support C++ 20, 19.28 or 16.9?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I saw that MSVC supports better than other compilers if I want to develop c++ 20 (in windows). And I found this in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support). But when I searched what is the latest Visual C++ version, I found that 16.9 is the latest version. But in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) it is saying that 19.28 is the latest version. So, what is the latest MSVC version?

Comment: Latest version is 16.9.5 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#--visual-studio-2019-version-1695-

Comment: Visual Studio (the IDE) is at 16.9.x; Visual C++ (the compiler) is at 19.x.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Internal_version_numbering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's slightly complicated...
The latest version of Visual Studio is [16.9.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#--visual-studio-2019-version-1695-) as of now. If you download that, you will have MSVC version 14.29 and the macro `_MSC_VER` will be defined as `1929`. Fortunately, you don't have to keep track of these for the most part to start out. Just install Visual Studio and get started.

Comment: It means latest version of visual studio contains the latest Visual c++??

Comment: @rajin100000 yes, that's generally the latest stable version afaik

Comment: I am trying to use std::counting_semaphore and I have updated VS to 16.10.3 so I am asuming MSVC version is at least 19.28, and when I include <semaphore>  I still get an error "std has no member countning_semaphore"